# First / bottom layers not printing?

Tags: resin, layer-height, print-failure, elegoo-saturn

New to the group so please let me know if I am not asking / formatting correctly.

So I have just started 3D resin printing with my new Elegoo Saturn. I have printed a couple of free STL files with no problem. I drew up a part for my modeling project with SketchUp maker. Exported the STL file into Chitubox and made a test print after slicing the file. The bottom layer(s) do not seem to print ... the bottom plate should be 4 mm but always prints at 2-3 mm. This makes my clearance groves almost disappear. What should be thru holes have a small layer closing the hole. The bottom layer seems to be "smashed out ... not a clean edge.

I have read, watched, studied lots of "help" on the web, make several slow changes to bottom layer print times, adjustments to lift / rest / etc, and lots more test prints which all have failed.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have another go with adding the photos - they're always helpful.  I can't get anything but an error from your links.

Comment: I fixed the images, they should be visible now. Thanks.

Comment: we experience exactly the same problems on a saturn s and saturn 2 - might be a software issue with chitubox...
Did you solve that problem?