# Resin LCD print not printing first layers properly, resulting in a reduction of the height of the object

Tags: troubleshooting, z-axis, resin

Printer: Elegoo Mars 3 LCD Resin Printer

I have a similar problem to this question, [First / bottom layers not printing?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/18583/first-bottom-layers-not-printing) and this issue on Reddit, [Elegoo Saturn Squishing Bottom Layers Together - Models Too Short](https://www.reddit.com/r/resinprinting/comments/otkln2/elegoo_saturn_squishing_bottom_layers_together/).

I am trying to print an object that is a cylinder with an engraving on it (the cylinder is not very high though, - it looks like the cylinder shown in this question on SE.Blender, [How can I engrave this Text on the side of this cylinder (without changing the style of the font)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262301/how-can-i-engrave-this-text-on-the-side-of-this-cylinder-without-changing-the-s)):

[image: Similar cylinder]

The cylinder is about 3.6 mm high only. It has an engraving on the side of it.

I haven't printed with supports but directly on the built plate (similar to the rook model Elegoo gives). The problem is that the first layers are not printed properly (it cuts off the engraving). This results in a reduction in the height of the cylinder.

Any solutions for how the first layers could come out properly?

Comment: Have you tried flipping the coin around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with printing directly on the build plate. The first few layers have to be cured for much longer than the rest of the layers in order to ensure that the model adheres properly to the build plate. This causes the layers to be thinner but wider. Often resulting in a slight brim around your model (Called an Elephant's foot in some circles).

Normally you would use a skate or raft and supports, so the distortion wouldn't be to the model itself.

You could reduce the number of bottom layers in your slicer, and reduce the exposure time, which will give you much closer to your expected height, but it may require a lot of trial and error printing to find the right settings for your printer. I think that some people have made calculators to help with this, or you could try to find a torture calibration model to help you find your optimum settings.

Personally, as a person who make models for printing, I would recommend that you changed the dimensions of your model, rather than changing your printer settings.

I often make the parts of my models that are in contact with the base slightly thicker, but with a slight bevel to the edge to allow for expansion (Elephant foot) , then I simply sand down the extra after printing till the model is of the desired size.

Again, this is mostly a matter of trial and error.

Comment: Seems like auto-beveling would be a nice feature to add to slicing software...